# error while deploying streamlit on nginx + docker

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, streamlit

i developed a simple multi page website using streamlit that communicates with various containerized backends, and i was trying to deploy it on nginx.

If i link the container port to localhost the website works perfectly, but if i try to depoly it the page loads it just says “please wait” and i get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q52dM.png)

I'm fairly new to all of this, but i think the error must be on my nginx configuration file, so i-ll leave it here.

```
upstream webapp{
    server webapp:8501;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp/;
    }
    location ^~ /static {
        proxy_pass http://webapp/static;
    }
    location _stcore/health {
        proxy_pass http://webapp/healthz;
    }
    location ^~ /vendor {
        proxy_pass http://webapp/vendor;
    }


    # location /stream {          # for old streamlit versions
    location ^~ _stcore/stream {   # new versions
        proxy_pass http://webapp/_stcore/stream;
        proxy_http_version 1.1; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}

    

}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me on this

What i tried:

- I’ve already read various issues on it, so i set in the .toml file of streamlit enableCORS = false , enableXsrfProtection=false and headless = true.
- Since old streamlit versions didn't have this issue, i tried to downgrade it, but the website i built needs streamlit 1.20 or higher
- Various changes on .conf locations, but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently moderators didn't like my other answer and deleted it, for future people who might have the same issue i'll leave the other solution i found

```
upstream webapp{
    server webapp:8501;
  }


server {
listen 80;

location / {
            proxy_pass http://webapp/;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

    location /_stcore/stream {
            proxy_pass http://webapp/_stcore/stream;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
```

}